# Adding minimum height to a list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am trying managing 4 lists under the same header as like it is posted in https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager. The problem I am facing is, my list has only fewer items on swiping pages, The header seems resizing. Is there a way to add a minimum height to the list to that it never falls  short of height.

Comment: I believe that you had you list view match_parent right? didn't that help?

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question properly. need more clarifications. maybe a screenshot

Comment: I mean I have suppose 10 items in first list and 4 in the second.I scroll the first list to bottom and thus my common header is also scrolled and now is collapsed. Then when I swipe to the list with four items what I see is a jerk as 4 items couldn't fill the whole page thus resizing the header.

Comment: post some screen shots please